# How to get the difference between two timestamps in a readable format in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL with two columns, `created_on` and `closed_on`, which contain timestamps in Unix milliseconds. I want to get the difference between these two timestamps in a readable format, such as "1 year, 9 days, 1 hour, 6 minutes, 1 second".

My initial table :

| id | created_on | closed_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1654850834025 | 1687168395586 |

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    (closed_on - created_on) * interval '1 millisecond' as interval1,
    justify_interval(32317561561 * interval '1 millisecond') as interval2,
    to_timestamp(closed_on / 1000)::timestamp - to_timestamp(created_on / 1000)::timestamp as interval3,
    to_timestamp(created_on / 1000)::timestamp as created_on,
    to_timestamp(closed_on / 1000)::timestamp as closed_on
FROM test
```

This query returns the following results:

| interval1 | interval2 | interval3 | created_on | closed_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"hours":8977,"minutes":6,"seconds":1,"milliseconds":561} | {"years":1,"days":14,"hours":1,"minutes":6,"seconds":1,"milliseconds":561} | {"days":374,"hours":1,"minutes":6,"seconds":1} | 2022-06-10T08:47:14.000Z | 2023-06-19T09:53:15.000Z |

However, the results are not as expected:

- interval1 only shows the hours, not the days, months, etc.
- interval2 incorrectly shows 14 days, when there should be 9 days in a year.
- interval3 shows the correct number of days, but it does not show the
  years or months.

**Expected result:**

```
1 year, 9 days, 1 hour, 6 minutes, 1 second
```

[image]

Fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnXPVmtBEBDih83ZutBMZ4/0

Comment: [`justify_interval` counts with 30-day months](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). Without a calendar and concrete start/end timestamps, that's the best you can do.

Comment: Why milliseconds when you have a timestamp (with time zone) available? Not to mention the data type tsrange, what would be the natural solution for your timestamp range created_on to closed_on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html, `justify_interval` counts with 30-day months and `timestamp` subtraction counts with 24-hour days. Without a calendar and concrete start/end timestamps, that's the best you can do.

It seems you are looking for the `age` function instead:

> `age ( timestamp, timestamp ) → interval`
>
> Subtract arguments, producing a “symbolic” result that uses years and
> months, rather than just days

```
SELECT age(to_timestamp(closed_on / 1000), to_timestamp(created_on / 1000))
FROM test
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HuaZ2HWV))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ever divide the epoch value by 1000? That is entirely different timestamp.

Also using justify_interval() you are saying to treat months as 30 days each, then it is 1 year and 14 days.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    created_on BIGINT NOT NULL,
    closed_on BIGINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (id, created_on, closed_on)
 VALUES (1, 1654850834025/1000, 1687168395586/1000);

select to_timestamp(created_on) created_on, 
       to_timestamp(closed_on) cloased_on,
       age( to_timestamp(closed_on) , to_timestamp(created_on)) "interval"
  from test;
```

| created_on | cloased_on | interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-10 09:47:14+01 | 2023-06-19 10:53:15+01 | 1 year 9 days 01:06:01 |

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/sTxRO9oz)

Comment: What is the purpose of dividing by 1000 in the insert statement?

Comment: @executable, did you check the dbfiddle code that is sent originally by the OP? I believe it is edited now, originally I got insert from there.